# Enabling PHP OP Cache

Tags: php, centos, php-ini, opcache

Looking for some help to properlly enabled OP Cache. For some reason it won't cache files. Below is the php.ini configuration and below that is a screenshot of this: https://gist.github.com/ck-on/4959032

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so

opcache.enable=1
opcache.fast_shutdown=0
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Any help would be much appriciated

---

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you've updated the correct ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marks comment pointed me in the right direction. I installed OP Cache using Yum and it generated its own .ini file that was being referenced and overriding my config changes in phg.ini.

To fix it I just removed my changes in php.ini and moved my config to the opcache.ini file...

Thanks again Mark!

Chuck